# Make UINavigationBar title editable

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationbar, title

I'd like to implement such feature in my project. It is just like changing title of `UINavigationBar` in Interface Builder. It's not a problem in terms of programming (maybe adding shadow to `UITextField` text is a little challenge, but not that big). My question is: is it in compliance with App Store Review Guidelines & Human Interface Guidelines
? Do you know such apps in App Store, or have you submitted such apps to App Store by yourself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/) does this in their iPad and iPhone version.